# Jquery dynamic Class Selector Not Working

Tags: jquery

I have written an on click event in which class is dynamic.

here is my code

### jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){      
      $('.offersidemenu li').click(function(){

      var sidemenu = $(this).text();
      alert(sidemenu); // Electronics is the output
     $('.' + sidemenu).css('border','5px solid green'); // not working 
   /* $('.Electronics').css('border','5px solid green'); Working  */
       });
    });
```

### HTML

```
<div class="color-shape Electronics Emi small rectangle">
----MY Content---
</div>
```

Comment: use $(this).text().trim()

Comment: Could you share the html of the _li_ tag?

Comment: @MarioAraque `<ul class="offersidemenu">      
         <div style="display: block; cursor: pointer;" >
      
      <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #F0F0F0;padding: 5px;">
           <a  href="#">       
       <li>
           <span>All Offers</span>
       </li>
          </a>
      </div>
        </ul>`

Comment: Your _li_ content is inside a span tag. You have to find the tag value instead of check the entire <li> value. Check my answer and hope it helps.

Comment: You should not be using text content to match other elements. I have added a number of suggestions/corrections below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some additional space is coming, it will make a problem. So trim the spaces before using it as selector

```
$('.offersidemenu li').click(function () {
    var sidemenu = $(this).text().trim();
    alert(sidemenu); // Electronics is the output
    $('.' + sidemenu).css('border', '5px solid green'); 
});
```

**Edit**

Suggested by  Frédéric Hamidi

It better to use `$.trim($(this).text())` for the support of lower vesions of IE

Comment: Consider `$.trim($(this).text())` if the code has to run on IE8 or lower.

Comment: The HTML is also invalid (unmatched DIV tags) and you should only have `LI`s under a `UL`. You also should not depend on text content for matching other elements as that leads to maintenance problem (use data attributes instead).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with both the HTML and the code.

As mentioned you may have problems with `text()` returning unwanted whitespace. Your HTML is also invalid as you have unmatched `DIV` tags and you should not surround an `LI` with an anchor and `DIV`s. The parent of an `LI` must be a `UL` or `OL`.

Rather than depend on text, and trim it (and fix any other issues), add a `data-` attribute to your elements. This is a more reliable and maintainable way of referencing other elements.

e.g. the HTML

```
<ul class="offersidemenu">
    <li data-link=".Electronics">
        <div style="display: block; cursor: pointer;">
            <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #F0F0F0;padding: 5px;"> <a href="#">   <span>All Offers</span> </a> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If the class is actually dynamically set (as you state in the title/question), then you need to use a delegated event handler:

```
// Shortcut for $(document).ready(
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.offersidemenu li', function (e) {
        // Stop the link moving to the top of the page
        e.preventDefault();
        // Fetch the data-link attribute
        var sidemenu = $(this).data("link");
        $(sidemenu).css('border', '5px solid green');
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/rcbk8zs5/

The delegated event handler works by listening for events bubbling up to a non-changing ancestor of the elements you want. The closer the better (for efficiency), but `document` is the default (if nothing closer is available). It *then* applies the jQuery selector. It *then* applies the function to *any matching elements that caused the event*.

*Delegated handlers have the advantage that the elements may not yet exist.*